# Can we use the JQuery , java scripts in Windowform using C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, winforms, c#-4.0

Please give me the detailed information about this
" can we use the JQuery, Java Script, bootstrap in Windowform application using C#"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, You can use the JQuery, JavaScript, bootstrap in Windows form Application. Please check this  : 
https://dzone.com/articles/create-a-desktop-application-using-angular-bootstr

Comment: it's ok to answer linking other resources, anyhow you should also put in your answer the relevant part that fixes the problem, links can die, while answer here in SO should be made to remain through time

Comment: ok firstly i checked the your sending link and then response you

Comment: interesting thanks sir.........:)